# C++ : Observer Pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, observers

How efficiently can I write setScore() without adding it to IObserver ? Is there any better to add such method ? or any better implementation than this ? PLEASE HELP.

ObserverPattern.cpp:88:7: error: ‘class IObservable’ has no member named ‘setScore’

```
//interface
class IObserver
{
public:
    virtual void update(int) = 0;   
};

//interface
class IObservable
{
public:
    virtual void subscribe(IObserver *) = 0;
    virtual void unsubscribe(IObserver *) = 0;
    virtual void notifyAll() = 0;   
};


class CricketMatchScore : public IObservable
{
    
public:

    CricketMatchScore()
    :   mScore (0)
    {

    }

    void subscribe(IObserver * obj)
    {
        mObservers.push_back(obj);
    }   

    virtual void unsubscribe(IObserver * obj)
    {
        auto iter = std::find(mObservers.begin(), mObservers.end(), obj);
        if (iter != mObservers.end())
        {
            mObservers.erase(iter);
        }
    }

    void notifyAll()
    {
        for (auto & item : mObservers)
        {
            item->update(mScore);
        }
    }

    void virtual setScore(int score)
    {
        if (mScore != score)
        {
            mScore = score;
            notifyAll();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<IObserver*> mObservers;
    int mScore;

};


class CricInfo : public IObserver
{
public:
    void update(int score)
    {
        std::cout<<score<<std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    IObserver * ob1 = new CricInfo;
    IObserver * ob2 = new CricInfo;

    IObservable * obl = new CricketMatchScore;

    obl->subscribe(ob1);
    obl->subscribe(ob2);

    obl->setScore(20);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Why use `IObservable*` as the type for `obl`, when you could use `CricketMatchScore*` (or actually `CricketMatchScore`, as there's no reason to use dynamic allocation here)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Fred. I was just going through implementation @ https://medium.com/@gayashanbc/explore-the-observer-design-pattern-with-c-8592459b0486 , so should we create interfaces in that case ? Will they still make sense if we are not going to use dynamic polymorphism and not trying to make things generic ?    Pardon me if my questions are silly.  Thanks.

Comment: In order to get the interface working with maximum generic-ness it would have to have virtual functions for all of the functions its client may need.  If the clients need `setScore`, `IObservable` needs `setScore`. The alternative is ugliness with the client `dynamic_cast`ing to a type with a `setScore` function, and as soon as the client needs to do that, say goodbye to claims of being generic.

Comment: Among these two implementations, which is better and why ?????  https://thispointer.com/designing-a-configurable-logging-framework-using-observer-design-pattern/   Vs     https://medium.com/@gayashanbc/explore-the-observer-design-pattern-with-c-8592459b0486

Answer (score 0):

Polymorphism/Function-overriding only works when you override a function(virtual) written in base class to behave differently in your derived class but here `setScore` is not declared in your base-class. So, Polymorphism won't work here. This is your best bet

```
 CricketMatchScore* ob3 = new CricketMatchScore(); //you already used ob1 above, it's a conflicting declaration in your code
```

[Check this Implementation of Observer pattern](https://thispointer.com/designing-a-configurable-logging-framework-using-observer-design-pattern/)

Comment: The best option would be `CricketMatchScore ob3;`. No need for `new` and the extra baggage it brings at all.

Comment: Ok, Got it. Thank you.